# Multiple Instances of Pending Intent

Tags: android, widget

I created a widget that when clicked activates a PendingIntent.  The problem is when I have more than one widget on the screen only the latest one will start the PendingIntent.

I have read some about a unique request code, but not figured this out.

Any ideas how I can have multiple widgets and the PendingIntents work for each?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Intent openApp = new Intent(context, RunningTally.class);
    openApp.putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent pendingAppIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openApp, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT  );
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.openFull, pendingAppIntent);
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

So happens that after posting my question, I came up with an answer.  I pass in my appWidgetId as the "unique" request code and voila!  Here is the snippet now:

```
Intent openApp = new Intent(context, RunningTally.class);
    openApp.putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent pendingAppIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, openApp, 
                                  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.openFull, pendingAppIntent);
```

Comment: The worst is that the documentation says: requestCode Private request code for the sender (currently not used). So I saw it, but I didn't try to use it because I thought it wouldn't work!

Comment: @thiagolr right without passing extra it wont work , eventhough u have pass same unique value in pending intent, +1  for it

Comment: Of note - it is not marked _currently not used_ anymore http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)

Comment: As i've noticed, this should work for any type of pending intent (including those of notifications). i think it's best to put a class that manages all of the types you have, to avoid overriding of them.

Comment: The key here is UNIQUE request code. If you pass two of the same - one will not work.

Comment: @android-developer yeah The concept of multiple instances of pending intent with different request codes works perfectly with `AlarmManager` too

Comment: Note: requestCode is useless for getBroadcast() type PendingIntent http://stackoverflow.com/a/33203752/2301224

Comment: I had two buttons so I used: int requestCode = (int)(Math.random() * 100);