# Problems starting activity from an AppWidget

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-appwidget

I have an application with an `AppWidget`. The `AppWidget` has some buttons which when clicked must open an `Activity`. The `Activity` must change some object's values depending on the `appWidgetId` of the `AppWidget` that has started this `Activity`. Here's a piece of code from the `AppWidgetProvider` subclass:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int id : appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);

        Intent localCodeIntent = new Intent(context,
                CountrySelectorActivity.class);

        localCodeIntent
                .setAction(CurrencyRatesWidgetHelper.WIDGET_UPDATE_LOCAL_CURRENCY);
        localCodeIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, id);
        PendingIntent localCodePI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                localCodeIntent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.local_iv, localCodePI);
```

The `Activity` starts well, but when I'm trying to extract the `appWidgetId`, I get the value of 1 everytime. Here's the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    appWidgetId = intent
            .getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);
    action = intent.getAction();
```

I'm sure I'm making a mistake somewhere, but can't really figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value do you see when you print out the id from the `onUpdate` method? If that is also `1`, then the id is `1`. Otherwise, you may need to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT to stop the Intent being reused (and possibly sharing a single widget id). Another trick to avoid caching of Intent is to put a unique random value in the Intent, e.g. `localCodePI.putExtra("random", Math.random())`.

Comment: @PaulGrime, I've tried both things, but the problem doesn't seem to be solved. Maybe, I misunderstand the mechanism of PendingIntents? Are they being created one for each widget when it's being created?

Comment: Could you try adding the random to `localCodeIntent` instead of `localCodePI`? I think I advised you incorrectly. Maybe you could also print the hashcode of the received Intent in the Activity to see if they are being shared?

Comment: @PaulGrime, I think I've figured out the things. I've tried using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and now I'm receiving updates for the latest widget I've created, no matter what widget did I click on. Is there any way to create a unique PendingIntent for one single Activity but with different extras?

Comment: @PaulGrime, P.S. The "random" trick doesn't seem to work.. I've added it to Intent actually.

Comment: @PaulGrime, OK, found the solution. Here's the link, if you might be interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730258/mulitple-instances-of-pending-intent. Thanks for your help!