# Android: AlarmManager not Working Long Interval Values

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm using `AlarmManager` for widget update transactions. I've different interval values like 5, 10, 15, 30 minutes etc.

How to call `AlarmManager`:

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);        

// Interval value, default 600 (600*1000 -> 10 min)
Long repeat = Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("update_preference", "600"));

// Set the manager
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 1000*repeat, pi);
```

So If user selects 5 or 10 minutes, it's okay. But if not, I mean, user selects bigger values like 15, 30, 60 minutes `MyService` not working as soon as `setRepetaing`.

What's difference or wrong?

Edit: It works instantly <30 minutes, but now work higher than 30 minutes with unique request codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use unique request code in PendingIntent

[Mulitple Instances of Pending Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730258/mulitple-instances-of-pending-intent)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168484/pendingintent-works-correctly-for-the-first-notification-but-incorrectly-for-the

Comment: Tried unique request codes and still has the same issue. Edited question.

Comment: have you used  i.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())) in conjunction with using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as mention in stackoverflow....

Answer (score 2):

```
pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 12345, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This could work, "0" isn't the best choice for an unique id.

Comment: 0 is may be not best okay. But, it works for 5 and 10 minutes. I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing changed, still not working for 30 and 60 minutes. Btw, there is no difference values' types.