# Android AppWidget not updating sometimes

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-appwidget

### The Problem

My `AppWidget` isn't updating when it should. I can't figure out why.

### Relevant Code

Here is my `app_widget_info.xml` file. `updatePeriodMillis` is set to zero because I update the widget manually using the `AlarmManager`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="250dp" android:minHeight="110dp" android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/app_widget"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/app_widget"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview_image" />
```

Here are the relevant portions of my `AppWidgetProvider` class:

```
public class MyAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static PendingIntent service1 = null, service2 = null, update_service = null;

    public static void nullifyService( String service_name ) {
        if ( service_name.equals( "service1" ) ) {
            service1 = null;
        } else {
            service2 = null;
        }
    }

    public static void updateMyWidget(final Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

        /* ... code to update my widget ... */
        /* ... this code is tested and I know it works ... */

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        // set alarms if necessary for the beginning and end of the next void
        if ( null ==  update_service || ( null == service1 && null == service2 ) ) {

            final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            // set alarms for the beginning and end of the upcoming/current event window
            if ( null == service1 && null == service1 ) {
                final Calendar s1_c = Calendar.getInstance(), // service1 alarm time
                               s2_c = Calendar.getInstance(); // service2 alarm time
                final Intent   s1_i = new Intent(context,MyService.class).putExtra( "serviceName", "service1" ),
                               s2_i = new Intent(context,MyService.class).putExtra( "serviceName", "service2" );
                final long s1_millis, s2_millis;

                // get the current VOC info
                if ( db == null ) db = new MyDataBase(context);
                alarm_info = db.getCurrentAlarms();

                // alarm times for service1 and service2 are UNIX timestamps
                // pulled from a sqlite database (tested and working fine)
                s1_c.setTime(new Date(alarm_info.getLong(4) * 1000 ));
                s2_c.setTime(new Date(alarm_info.getLong(1) * 1000 ));

                // if it is still before the next service1 alarm time
                // set an alarm for the exact time
                if ( s1_c.getTimeInMillis() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() ) {
                    s1_c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                    s1_c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    service1 = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, s1_i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );
                    s1_millis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + s1_c.getTime().getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
                    m.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, s1_millis, service1);
                }

                // set the alarm for the service2 alarm time
                s2_c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                s2_c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                service2  = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, s2_i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );
                s2_millis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + s2_c.getTime().getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
                m.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, s2_millis, service2);
            }

            // set the widget to update every 15 minutes regardless
            if ( null == update_service ) {
                final Intent up_i = new Intent(context,MyService.class).putExtra( "serviceName", "update" );
                update_service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2, up_i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 15 * 60 * 1000, update_service);
            }
        }

        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for( int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateMyWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
        final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        m.cancel(service1);
        m.cancel(service2);
        m.cancel(update_service);
    }
}
```

And here are the relevant portions of my `Service` class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

        // update all of the widgets
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, MyAppWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager m = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        for ( int awid : m.getAppWidgetIds(cn) ) {
            MyAppWidget.updateMyWidget(this,m,awid);
        }
        String service_name = intent.getStringExtra( "serviceName" );
        if ( "service1" == service_name || "service2" == service_name ) {
            MyAppWidget.nullifyService(service_name);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

### What I Know and What I've Tried

1. The `update_service` works fine and updates the widget dependably every 15 minutes
2. The alarms for `service1` and `service2` are being set.

Here is a snippet from running `adb shell dumpsys alarm` showing one of the repeating alarms (that fires every 15 minutes, or 900000ms):

```
ELAPSED #0: Alarm{41a9e1b8 type 3 com.mycompany.myappwidget}
    type=3 whenElapsed=231265839 when=+11m52s295ms window=-1 repeatInterval=900000 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{41dbf158: PendingIntentRecord{41cf7920 com.mycompany.myappwidget startService}}
```

And here is another showing one of the alarms that is set to fire at an exact time:

```
ELAPSED #4: Alarm{433d1560 type 3 com.mycompany.myappwidget}
    type=3 whenElapsed=90066209 when=+4h34m36s121ms window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{41f0ec28: PendingIntentRecord{41f1e690 com.mycompany.myappwidget startService}}
```

And here are the stats for the alarms that have already fired where `d` and `c` refer to the services that got started:

```
com.mycompany.myappwidget +1s857ms running, 0 wakeups:
    +1s817ms 0 wakes 83 alarms: cmp={com.mycompany.myappwidget/com.mycompany.myappwidget.d}
    +40ms 0 wakes 1 alarms: cmp={com.mycompany.myappwidget/com.mycompany.myappwidget.c}
```

As you can see, the alarms **are** being triggered, but the interface is not updating.

3. Since the repeating alarm fires reliably every 15 minutes, I don't think that the OS is killing them based on the restriction of only updating widgets every 30 minutes
4. I have tried creating a different `Service` class for each alarm in order to avoid the alarms canceling each other as is [suggested by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526319/whats-requestcode-used-for-on-pendingintent)
5. I have used `Log` statements to confirm that the `updateMyWidget()` function is actually being called when each alarm is triggered. It appears that the function is called, but doesn't always update the widgets.
6. I have tried setting different unique `requestCode`s for each `PendingIntent` so that when a new alarm is set, it doesn't inadvertently cancel the `PendingIntent`s set by other alarms

### Questions and Ideas

Am I doing this wrong? On average, updates only seem to take about 200ms, so perhaps I should be using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` and calling `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` instead of creating a `Service` to handle the updates. This is driving me nuts, so any hints or clues that might point me in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

### UPDATE

@Karakuri's answer taught me how to differentiate `PendingIntent` objects for the purposes of not having them overwrite each other when setting alarms. Here's how I fixed this code:

1. I changed the `putExtra()` calls to `setAction()` and set the action as one of the predefined constants, e.g. `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`, that seemed semantically similar to what the service was doing
2. I removed all of the services from the class-level scope, as it turns out it was unnecessary to keep them around in between calls to `onUpdate()`
3. I got rid of all of the conditional logic inside of `onUpdate()`
4. I went back to using the built-in android update mechanism, i.e. changed the `android:updatePeriodMillis` in `app_widget_info.xml` to `1800000` (30 minutes) and got rid of the repeating alarm I'd set with `setRepeating()`
5. I discovered that there was a problem with the boundary conditions for my alarms that was preventing the UI from updating when I thought it should--I wouldn't have discovered this, though, if I hadn't started using `setAction()`

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I have a few suggestions, but I don't know which (if any) will solve your problem as I'm not entirely sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my suggestions, hopefully somewhere in here is something that fixes your issue.

1. Don't use `==` to compare strings in your service (or anywhere). Use `.equals()` with named constants.
2. Your `PendingIntent`s only differ by extras. When you give the same `Intent` to `PendingIntent`, it only keeps one of them. For the purposes of comparing `Intent`s, **extras are not considered** (see the documentation of `PendingIntent` about this). Instead of using the extras, I would give each `Intent` a different action and use `intent.getAction()` in your Service.
3. Don't rely on static variables for keeping state. Your process can be shut down any time and you will lose that data. Your AppWidget is running in a different process, so unless you have something else running, Android may decide to clear your process. I would use some kind of persistent storage, probably `SharedPreferences` if it's just for a handful of keys.

Comment: tyvm!! per suggestion 3, since my static class variables are objects and not scalars, would you recommend [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15588512/296725) for storing the objects for later retrieval? Also is that Karakuri as in からくりテレビ？

Comment: I wouldn't store them. I see you are keeping them around so you can cancel them in `onDisabled()`, but really I think it's better to just reconstruct the `PendingIntent`s. You can refactor that logic into a method to make sure they are built the same way each time.