# Appwidget click intents across multiple instances

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have a widget that links to an activity in my app. I link the `PendingIntent` for this like so inside my `AppWidgetProvider`:

```
public class SampleWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate([…]) {
        RemoteViews views = […]

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY, extraValue);
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.view_name, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The `extraValue` is based on the content widget is displaying, so it could be shared by some widgets, but not always by all. I've tried logging the assigned value here, and I can confirm that the correct value is being stored for the correct widgets. When I tap on the `View` with the ID `view_name` in **any** widget, however, I get the value from the first widget created (since phone reboot) in the launched Activity, not the value of the specific widget I tapped on. It seems that there may be some sort of single instance of the `View` and that assigning multiple `PendingIntent`s to it with `setOnClickPendingIntent()` is causing only the first one to be used? Is there a way to attach data to the Intent without code in the Activity to determine what to show based on calling widget?

Comment: the second parameter passed to `getActivity` should be unique, not 0

Comment: That was absolutely the problem! Please write up an answer so I can accept it! ([A good reference question about the use of the `requestCode` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526319/whats-requestcode-used-for-on-pendingintent))

Comment: hmm , one guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526319/whats-requestcode-used-for-on-pendingintent#comment54219506_21526319) (a reference question you posted above) claims it does not work any longer (22+ API), tried on API >= 22?

Comment: The [next comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526319/whats-requestcode-used-for-on-pendingintent#comment54222581_21526319) says it might be a bug? If it is ignored, it's a great placebo because I made the change to a unique ID (using the widget ID), and it works brilliantly.

Comment: yep, but what API version you are working with? did you try it on 22+?

Comment: My target (and test device) is `25`.

Comment: so maybe its limited to `getBroadcast` only, i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) in comments on the original question, the issue is caused by the use of a `0` value for the `requestCode` parameter in `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. Replacing it with a unique ID (such as the widget's ID) resolves the issue:

```
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, 0);
```

This is because the `requestCode` is used as an identifier to differentiate individual `PendingIntent`s from one another.