# Android Power Screen `Control` always takes the same intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-device-controls

I am cooperating with TheLastProject@github on an app that works as a loyalty card wallet: Catima (link to [my fork](https://github.com/Zighinetto/Catima/tree/feature/%23146-power-screen-widgets) and to [app listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.hackerchick.catima))

I tried to implement [Power screen cards](https://github.com/TheLastProject/Catima/issues/146) and I followed the Android development guide on [Device Controls](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/device-control)

The [resulting code](https://github.com/TheLastProject/Catima/pull/427) is (this [link](https://github.com/TheLastProject/Catima/pull/427/files#diff-8dca02471f309ee3d747169e9a32e963d5d49d15c3adbc1aa27ad7e7776f3a66R55) could be invalidated during a rebase) has prblems

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Flow.Publisher<Control> createPublisherFor(@NonNull List<String> controlIds) {
    return subscriber -> {
        subscriber.onSubscribe(new NoOpSubscription());
        for (String controlId : controlIds) {
            Integer cardId = this.controlIdToCardId(controlId);
            if (cardId == null)
                continue;
            LoyaltyCard card = dbHelper.getLoyaltyCard(cardId);
            Intent openIntent = new Intent(this, LoyaltyCardViewActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    .putExtra("id", card.id);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            var ret = new Control.StatefulBuilder(controlId, pendingIntent)
                    .setTitle(card.store)
                    .setDeviceType(DeviceTypes.TYPE_GENERIC_OPEN_CLOSE)
                    .setSubtitle(card.note)
                    .setStatus(Control.STATUS_OK)
                    .setControlTemplate(new StatelessTemplate(controlId))
                    .setCustomIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(Utils.generateIcon(this, card.store, card.headerColor).getLetterTile()))
                    .build();
            Log.d(TAG, "Dispatching widget " + controlId);
            subscriber.onNext(ret);
        }
        subscriber.onComplete();
    };
}
```

### Code design

Loyalty cards are identified by an integer. I have generated unique control IDs based on that integer, so that I can query them. As told me by the Maintainer, `LoyaltyCardViewActivity` is the view that can be used to display a loyalty card, and the intent looks genuine.

So for each card in the input, I iterate and *reactively* emit a new `Control` for each card. Each control has its own intent and every intent is bound to the card ID.

### Problem

The problem is that when I long-press on the widget, the intent emitted by Android carries the same card ID, which means that no matter I select different widgets, the same (not so deterministic) card is displayed.

"Not so deterministic". When I remove all controls and add them again, I can't predict which card is displayed. But every time I open the power menu again I get the same card.

In Android studio I debugged and I see the very same card ID passed to `LoyaltyCardViewActivity`, despite when I create the `Control` object I can clearly debug that the intent carries always a different ID

### How to reproduce

Works on the emulator. I used a dump of real loyalty cards and an EU digital green certificate. But one could create two or more barcode cards by inputting random numbers.

### Question

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

You are calling this N times, and so my guess is that you expect that you are creating N distinct `PendingIntent` objects. In reality, you are only creating one, because your `PendingIntent` identifier is the same for all of them: `0`.

Change this to be something more like:

```java
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, cardId, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

(I am guessing that `cardId` is unique for all your cards)

Comment: I think it will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526319/whats-requestcode-used-for-on-pendingintent