# Android - on sansung j5 Pending intent call does not work properly

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

**I wrote a service to call pending intent after 1 minute**

*code:*

```
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                            60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

this code works properly on all devices except samsung j5.Where it calls service after 5 minutes.

Please let me know what could be the possible reason for this issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577296/weird-alarmmanager-behaviour/37677048#37677048 On most newer devices you cannot set repeating alarms reliably. Especially low-end devices have severe restrictions on alarms to save battery life. For short intervals you are better off posting `Runnable` to a `Handler`.