# Android reminer reads only one alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have reminder app. [**This**](https://github.com/donnfelker/Task-Reminder) is the source code. The problem is that when I set one alarm then everything is fine. But when I set for example three alarm, my app only reads last alarm, it only reminds third alarm and it ignores first two alarms. Can you help me to set properly alarmManager so it would schedule every notification in specific time?

This is ReminderManager.java:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ReminderManager {

    private Context mContext; 
    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    public ReminderManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context; 
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when) {

        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId); 

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }
}
```

This is RemindersDbAdapter.java:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Simple reminder database access helper class. 
 * Defines the basic CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete)
 * for the example, and gives the ability to list all reminders as well as
 * retrieve or modify a specific reminder.
 * 
 */
public class RemindersDbAdapter {

    //
    // Databsae Related Constants
    //
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time"; 
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";


    private static final String TAG = "ReminderDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    /**
     * Database creation SQL statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_BODY + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);"; 



    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }


    public RemindersDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public RemindersDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new reminder using the title, body and reminder date time provided. 
     * If the reminder is  successfully created return the new rowId
     * for that reminder, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the reminder
     * @param body the body of the reminder
     * @param reminderDateTime the date and time the reminder should remind the user
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createReminder(String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime); 

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the reminder with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all reminders in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all reminders
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the reminder that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching reminder, if found
     * @throws SQLException if reminder could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

                mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the reminder using the details provided. The reminder to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title, body and reminder date time
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of reminder to update
     * @param title value to set reminder title to
     * @param body value to set reminder body to
     * @param reminderDateTime value to set the reminder time. 
     * @return true if the reminder was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I have to use this database values to store the alarm values?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `PendingIntent` part, although it is said

```
public static PendingIntent getBroadcast (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

> requestCode   Private request code for the sender (currently not used).

It is used, you need to use different requestCodes for different PendingIntents, or the system will think they are one PendingIntent but reset many times, which is your problem here.

Discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730258/mulitple-instances-of-pending-intent)