# startActivity not working when calling from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-broadcast

I have a notification and when I select, it sends a `Broadcast` to a `BroadcastReceiver` using a `PendingIntent`. In the `onReceive` I start a new `Activity`.

However, if I remove my app from recent apps opened (or the notification sit in the draw for a long time) this scenario occurs:

When I have multiple notifications in the drawer the first one opens great. After tapping on the second one my `onCreate()` nor my `onResume()` are being called and its as if the `startActivity()` is not working at all. If I add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` then `onNewIntent` is being called.

```
notificationIntent = new Intent();
notificationIntent.setAction(AppConstants.ACTION_ACTIVITY);
notificationIntent.putExtra("key", value);
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(context, requestID, notificationIntent, 
                                  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

onReceive

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
  intent.putExtra("key", value);
  //IF I ADD FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP IT WORKS
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is `Activity` is `LAUNCHER` and `MAIN` Activity ?

Comment: No Activity is not `LAUNCHER`

Comment: that's why getting issue. problem get fixed or still facing issue?

Comment: Still not fixed. I want to go to an Activity that is not my launcher. How should I define this so I dont need to call `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`?

Comment: @user1163234: when you press on the second notification: is the activity still running in front? Or is it running in the background or completely closed (finished)?

Comment: @Trinimon It is still in the front. But my onResume is not being called either....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using flags as follows for the intent.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```

And for Pending intent use    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: When I add 'Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK' it removes the backstack of the app. Any way around that?

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` saved my life.

Answer (score 5):

For someone, who will look for a similar question. Beginning from Android Q it's [restricted](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) to launch any activity, when app in background. To launch your activity, you need to displaying a notification with `PRIORITY_HIGH` and set the [full-screen intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)). So, totally you should have something like this:

```
//Create your intent as usual
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", value);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

// Build a pending intent 
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//Notification builder
NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pIntent, true /*isHighPriority*/);

NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nManager.notify(10, notifyBuilder.build())
```

This will display notification and will launch your activity immediately. And in your activity `onStart()` you can dismiss a notification like below:

```
NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nManager.cancel(10);
```

**NOTE**: Don't forget to init channel. Beginning from Android O it's a mandatory thing

Comment: Using the above core on wear os, I am not able to open the app. But I am able to generate the notification. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

in order to start activity from BroadcastReciever you should add flag of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

```
 Intent imap =new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                  imap.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  context.startActivity(imap);
```

Comment: I already have this flag but still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

An activity can be started from Broadcast Receiver even if it is not a launcher. That shouldn't be the problem.

Try passing a unique requestid,

```
notificationIntent = new Intent();
notificationIntent.setAction(AppConstants.ACTION_ACTIVITY);
notificationIntent.putExtra("key", value);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, value, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

See this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730258/mulitple-instances-of-pending-intent)

Comment: This is my `requestID`: `int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();`