# Wear OS - How to automatically start app on device restart

Tags: android, wear-os, reboot, relaunch

I've created a Wear OS app. It has a service running in the foreground. I need to have the app always executing. When I restart the watch the app doesn't start executing again. How can I automatically relaunch the app?

It's my first app for Wear OS and I don't know how to search for this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, and it's a bad idea for an app to do in most cases.  But I believe

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

This will wake up your broadcast receiver so you can run some code, but as you discovered you are probably restricted against starting an activity.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: Receiver is called but not able to open the app using the intent. Also not getting any error.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense.  Probably relates to background restrictions https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

I guess posting a notification from that boot event is the most you can do?

Comment: I have already tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/57869617/2024527 
by which I am able to generate the notification but not able to open the app.